# How to get parentnode of select element in javascript

Tags: javascript, html-select, parent-node

I am trying to alter the background color of a table cell if the selected item in a dropdown is changed.  I use the same javascript for a textbox and it works fine.  In firebug, "cell" is undefined when called from the select.

Here is my script/html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
 <head runat="server">
  <title>Untitled Page</title>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeText(cell, shown, hidden)
    {
     if (shown == hidden)
     {
      cell.style.backgroundColor="red";
     }
     else
     {
      cell.style.backgroundColor="green";
     }
    }
   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <table cellpadding="5">
     <tr>
      <td>
       Cell 1
      </td>
     <td>
      <select id="catBlah" OnChange="changeText(this.parentnode, this.options[this.selectedIndex].value, '789');">
       <option value=""></option>
       <option selected="selected" value="789">Item 1</option>
       <option value="000">Item 2</option>
       <option value="456">Item 3</option>
       <option value="123">Item 4</option>
      </select>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <input type="text" value="blue" onchange="changeText(this.parentNode, this.value, 'blue');" />
     </td>
     <td>
      Cell 4
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

If I just pass the select object (using "this" instead of "this.parentnode"), I can change the select's background color (which might meet requirements), but I can't figure out how to get the parentnode.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's [`parentNode`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/parentNode) (note the casing)

Comment: I could have sworn I checked that.  Thanks.

Comment: @monkeypushbutton: You'd actually got it right on the `input`, just not the `select`! :)

Comment: Yeah, that explains why it worked for one but not the other.  That's usually the first thing I check when some JS isn't working (wrong case).

Comment: @monkeypushbutton: I know, sometimes it's hard to see the wood for the trees.  That's why the error console is your friend :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your code was working (I may have fixed it by fiddling with it). It looks like it was your casing. Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/kaleb/y6UuL/

It appears that you were just not able to see the background color. I added padding to your cell.